# T-SQL datetime rounded to nearest minute and nearest hours with using functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to get datetime column rounded to nearest hour and nearest minute preferably with existing functions.

For this column value `2007-09-22 15:07:38.850`, the output will look like:

```
2007-09-22 15:08 -- nearest minute
2007-09-22 15    -- nearest hour
```

Comment: [TSQL Rounding or Truncating Date Time to Nearest Day, Hour, Minute or Second](https://stevestedman.com/2021/08/tsql-rounding-or-truncating-date-time-to-nearest-day-hour-minute-or-second/)

Answer (score 257, accepted):

```
declare @dt datetime

set @dt = '09-22-2007 15:07:38.850'

select dateadd(mi, datediff(mi, 0, @dt), 0)
select dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, @dt), 0)
```

will return

```
2007-09-22 15:07:00.000
2007-09-22 15:00:00.000
```

The above just truncates the seconds and minutes, producing the results asked for in the question.  As @OMG Ponies pointed out, if you want to round up/down, then you can add half a minute or half an hour respectively, then truncate:

```
select dateadd(mi, datediff(mi, 0, dateadd(s, 30, @dt)), 0)
select dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, dateadd(mi, 30, @dt)), 0)
```

and you'll get:

```
2007-09-22 15:08:00.000
2007-09-22 15:00:00.000
```

---

Before the [date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) data type was added in SQL Server 2008, I would use the above method to truncate the time portion from a datetime to get only the date.  The idea is to determine the number of days between the datetime in question and a fixed point in time (`0`, which implicitly casts to `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`):

```
declare @days int
set @days = datediff(day, 0, @dt)
```

and then add that number of days to the fixed point in time, which gives you the original date with the time set to `00:00:00.000`:

```
select dateadd(day, @days, 0)
```

or more succinctly:

```
select dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, @dt), 0)
```

Using a different datepart (e.g. `hour`, `mi`) will work accordingly.

Comment: I doubt anyone else will run into this, but if you are trying to round UP to the nearest second and adding on 500 milliseconds you'll want to do datediff(second, '1/1/2000', .... vs datediff(second, 0 .... as you'll get an overflow error. seconds from 0 is too big I guess.

Comment: 'Add the number of hours since Jan 1st 1900, to Jan 1st 1900' — I encountered this in Java/SQL, where it looks ugly. In my case it really should have been done on the Java side.

Comment: For computations with `datetimeoffset`, I had to substitute `0` with `TODATETIMEOFFSET('1900-01-01 00:00:00', 0)` to avoid forcing the local time zone onto the result.

Comment: '10-23-2020 14:59:59.999' gives 2020-10-23 15:00:00.000 while '10-23-2020 14:59:59.998' 2020-10-23 14:00:00.000

Comment: @mit - `DATETIME` has precision "only" 3.33 μs, so '14:59:59.999' gets stored as '15:00:00.000' and '14:59:59.998' as '14:59:59.997'

Comment: The round method does not work when you have 28 seconds so that means also when you have 58 seconds if you changed it to subtract 30 seconds

Answer (score 32):

I realize this question is ancient and there is an accepted and an alternate answer.  I also realize that my answer will only answer half of the question, but for anyone wanting to **round to the nearest minute and still have a datetime compatible value using only a single function**:

```
CAST(YourValueHere as smalldatetime);
```

For hours or seconds, use Jeff Ogata's answer (the accepted answer) above.

Comment: Excellent answer, I've verified that it does round and not just truncate. For anyone else looking into this option, `smalldatetime` was added in SQL 2008.

Comment: This is the best option if you're in need of fixing some data in your table that only requires time out to the minute.

Answer (score 28):

"Rounded" down as in your example. This will return a varchar value of the date.

```
DECLARE @date As DateTime2
SET @date = '2007-09-22 15:07:38.850'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @date, 120) --2007-09-22 15:07
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), @date, 120) --2007-09-22 15
```

Comment: Convert the varchar back to datetime could do (for hour): `CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), @date, 120)+':00:00')`

Answer (score 4):

In the new SQL Server 2022, and in Azure SQL, **you can use the [`DATETRUNC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetrunc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function**:

```sql
SELECT DATETRUNC(minute, @yourDate)
SELECT DATETRUNC(hour, @yourDate)
```

**You can also use the `DATE_BUCKET` function** if you want to round to an arbitrary number of hours or minutes

```sql
SELECT DATE_BUCKET(minute, 3, @yourDate)
SELECT DATE_BUCKET(hour, 3, @yourDate)
```

You can even give it a fourth parameter with a starting point, [see the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-bucket-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Answer (score -1):

`Select convert(char(8), DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, getdate), 0), 108) as Time`

will round down seconds to 00

Comment: Very slow, and does not round off as the OP asked, but rounds down, for which he did not ask. (Disclaimer - I did not down-vote you)

Answer (score -1):

Though there is an accepted answer for so long here I would like to point out that OP's desired output was

```
2007-09-22 15:08 -- nearest minute
2007-09-22 15    -- nearest hour
```

So, for nearest minute I have just added 30 seconds and collected the value up to minute by converting it into varchar. And for nearest minute I have added 30 minutes and collected the value up to hour part. Voila!!!

Query:

```
declare @dt datetime

set @dt = '09-22-2007 15:07:38.850'
select convert(varchar(16),dateadd(SECOND,30,@dt),120) nearest_minute
```

Output:

| nearest_minute |
| --- |
| 2007-09-22 15:08 |

Query:

```
declare @dt datetime
set @dt = '09-22-2007 15:07:28.850'
select convert(varchar(16),dateadd(SECOND,30,@dt),120) nearest_minute
```

Output:

| nearest_minute |
| --- |
| 2007-09-22 15:07 |

Query:

```
declare @dt datetime
set @dt = '09-22-2007 15:07:38.850'
select convert(varchar(13),dateadd(MINUTE,30,@dt),120) nearest_hour
```

Output:

| nearest_hour |
| --- |
| 2007-09-22 15 |

Query:

```
declare @dt datetime
set @dt = '09-22-2007 15:30:28.850'
select convert(varchar(13),dateadd(MINUTE,30,@dt),120) nearest_hour
```

Output:

| nearest_hour |
| --- |
| 2007-09-22 16 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/c4ibqhUb)