# SQL Server - Round TIME values to the next minute

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, rounding, sqldatetime

I've found many posts about rounding "down" time values (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6667041/468823), but I have another problem: I wanna round to the higher minute and not to the lower, how can I do?

My code:

```
SELECT

 PA.ORE AS TOT_HOURS,  
 CAST(CAST(PA.ORA_INIZIO AS DATETIME) AS TIME) AS BEGIN_TIME,
 CAST(dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, (CAST(PA.ORA_INIZIO AS DATETIME))), 0) AS TIME) AS BEGIN_TIME_ROUNDED


FROM PRG_ATTIVITA PA INNER JOIN PRG_TIPI_ATTIVITA PTA ON  PA.ID_TIPO_ATTIVITA = PTA.ID_TIPO_ATTIVITA
                     INNER JOIN PER_ANAGRAFICA PAN ON PA.ID_DIPENDENTE = PAN.ID_DIPENDENTE
WHERE PA.ID_PROGETTO = 1431 and pta.DESCR_TIPO_ATTIVITA like 'F-%remoto%' and ID_ATTIVITA = 41772 

ORDER BY  PA.DATA_ATTIVITA
```

My result is the following:

```
    TOT_HOURS   BEGIN_TIME          BEGIN_TIME_ROUNDED
    1.50        15:59:59.9970000    15:59:00.0000000
```

**I want BEGIN_TIME_ROUNDED = 16:00:00.0000000**

NOTES:
1. I must convert my data { CAST(PA.ORA_INIZIO AS DATETIME) } because in the database I have time data as float values
2. BEGIN_TIME is the real value of my time value after conversion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  DATEADD(MINUTE, CEILING(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, CAST(CAST(PA.ORA_INIZIO AS DATETIME) AS TIME)) / 60.0), DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, PA.ORA_INIZIO)) AS BEGIN_TIME_ROUNDED
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out in a comment this fails for times between 0 and 1 second. This can be combatted by simply changing the precision in the ceiling from seconds to milliseconds:

```
SELECT  PA.ORA_INIZIO,
        DATEADD(MINUTE, 
            CEILING(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, 0, CAST(PA.ORA_INIZIO AS TIME)) / 60000.0),
            DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, PA.ORA_INIZIO)) AS BEGIN_TIME_ROUNDED
FROM (VALUES 
        (CONVERT(DATETIME, '20211126 15:59:00.997')), 
        (CONVERT(DATETIME, '20211126 15:59:00.004'))
    ) AS PA (ORA_INIZIO);
```

Which gives:

| ORA_INIZIO | BEGIN_TIME_ROUNDED |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-11-26 15:59:59.997 | 2021-11-26 16:00:00.000 |
| 2021-11-26 15:59:00.003 | 2021-11-26 16:00:00.000 |

Comment: This will not work when the time column is more than 0 second and less than 1 second. In this case the syntax will round down

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Thank you for the feedback. I have modified the answer to deal with this case.

Answer (score 2):

Just CAST to smalldatetime for rounding to nearest minute

```
SELECT 
    CAST(CAST('15:59:59.9970000' AS time) AS smalldatetime),
    CAST(CAST('15:59:30.0030000' AS time) AS smalldatetime),
    CAST(CAST('15:59:30.0000000' AS time) AS smalldatetime),
    CAST(CAST('15:59:29.9970000' AS time) AS smalldatetime),
    CAST(CAST('15:59:00.0030000' AS time) AS smalldatetime)
```

The DATEADD/DATEDIFF is for truncating some time unit

Edit, misread questions

Just modify your current CAST

```
CAST(
 DATEADD(minute,
         DATEDIFF(minute, 
                  0, 
                  CAST(PA.ORA_INIZIO AS DATETIME)
                 ) + 1, 
         0
         )
     AS TIME)
```

Comment: -1 This does not answer the question at all. The OP wants to always round up to the nearest minute, the solution you have posted will round normally to the nearest minute, i.e. the last 2 columns of your select statement round down to 15:59 rather than up to 16:00.

Comment: @GarethD: fixed it, I missed that. Thanks

Comment: there is a problem '20:30' will be rounded up to '20:31'

Comment: it is a ceiling question. 20:30 should not be rounded up. At least not how i read the question. You are just rounding down and adding 1 minute

Answer (score 1):

Don't know SQL Server well enough to answer off hand, but if no one comes by with a more more de facto way of doing this, then you could just add 1 minute to the value before rounding it down. Or add 0.999 minutes if you need to handle integer input values correctly as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to round DATETIME d up to the nearest minute, you could do this:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,
  DATEADD(minute, CASE WHEN d = CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, d) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  d)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ datetime = '2021-11-26 00:00:00.997'
SELECT dateadd(minute, ceiling(cast(@ as float) * 1440),0) ceilingminute
```