# one issue in sql,i want next minute of current date/time

Tags: sql

by using `GETDATE()`,i can get `current date` and `time` like `2019-11-20 15:04:22` but i need next minute like `2019-11-20 15:05:00`

Comment: This is already answered.Please have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760529/how-to-add-minutes-to-the-time-part-of-datetime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add minutes to the time part of datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760529/how-to-add-minutes-to-the-time-part-of-datetime)

Comment: in standard SQL this would be `current_timestamp + interval '1' minute`

Answer (score 0):

```
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,
  DATEADD(minute, CASE WHEN d = CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, d) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  d)))
```

Taken from here:
[SQL Server - Round TIME values to the next minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274457/sql-server-round-time-values-to-the-next-minute)

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to calculate the number of minutes since some point in time, add 1, and add that back to the original point in time.

`0` is a convenient time for this purpose:

```
select dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, dt) + 1, 0)
from (values (convert(datetime, '2019-11-20 15:04:22'))) v(dt)
```