# Truncate date to only hour / minute

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How do i trunc the date in sql server 2008 like this :

I have `2012-01-02 12:04:11.443` and I want only to select `2012-01-02 12:00:00.000` and `2012-01-02 12:04:00.000` (hour and minute level)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I truncate a datetime in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923295/how-can-i-truncate-a-datetime-in-sql-server)

Comment: In particular, see BG100's answer in that thread.

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL datetime rounded to nearest minute and nearest hours with using functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666866/t-sql-datetime-rounded-to-nearest-minute-and-nearest-hours-with-using-functions)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
declare @D as datetime = '2012-01-02T12:04:11.443'

select dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, @D), 0)
select dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, @D), 0)
```

Comment: This is so much cleaner than any other solution I've seen, it's worth a vote and a comment.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I must've gotten something wrong

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 6):

As of SQL Server 2022 CTP 2.1, there is a native function in SQL to do this called `DATETRUNC()`.  You can pick the date/time level to which you would like to truncate the date.  Documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetrunc-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

```sql
DATETRUNC(hour, YourDate)
```

Comment: There is also `DATE_BUCKET`

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work:

```
select [Rounded Time] =
    dateadd(mi,datediff(mi,0,dateadd(ss,30,a.DT)),0)

from
    (
    select dt = convert(datetime,'8:24:29.997')
    union all
    select dt = convert(datetime,'8:24:30.000')
    ) a
```

Results:

```
Rounded Time                                           
------------------------------------------------------ 
1900-01-01 08:24:00.000
1900-01-01 08:25:00.000

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: thank you for answer .. Mikael Eriksson has a more simple answer. Also + 1 for the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm using something like this:

```
DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF(hour,'2000-01-01 00:00',[timestamp]),'2000-01-01 00:00')
```

You can use this formula to truncate to other levels, ie minutes:

```
DATEADD(minutes,DATEDIFF(minutes,'2000-01-01 00:00',[timestamp]),'2000-01-01 00:00')
```

You must remember that if you are truncating to seconds level, the maximum difference between the base date and [timestamp] is 68 years.