# Group by date and hour

Tags: sql, sql-server

I like see if there is a way to get the same result as this script below with a one liner or just a lot less code. The script below works but I think there is a lot of over head here and the table is rather large.

(EDIT: The code below **truncates** DATETIME to the hour)

```
SELECT Convert(varchar,DATEPART(year, getdate()))
    +'-'+
    Case
        When Convert(varchar,DATEPART(month, getdate()))<=9 Then '0'+Convert(varchar,DATEPART(month, getdate()))
            Else Convert(varchar,DATEPART(month, getdate()))
    End
    +'-'+
    Case
        When Convert(varchar,DATEPART(day, getdate()))<=9 Then '0'+Convert(varchar,DATEPART(day, getdate()))
            Else Convert(varchar,DATEPART(day, getdate()))
    End 
    +' '+Convert(Varchar,DatePart(Hour,Getdate()))
    +':00:00.00'
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If 2022 `SELECT DATETRUNC(Hour, Getdate())` will give you a value truncated to the hour that you can use for grouping. Otherwise `SELECT  dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, Getdate()), 0)`

Comment: Show sample data and desired results.

Comment: I wish that people weren't so bloody quick at closing posts because of a supposed "Already Answered" reason because the accepted answer on that other post is NOT the best answer,

Comment: @JeffModen Yeah, strange duplicate choice. I'll vote to re-open

Comment: @JeffModen the accepted answer being the best answer (in your opinion) is irrelevant to whether the question is a duplicate or not. It is a duplicate because it is asking how to achieve the same goal ("Group by date and hour") If you have a better answer (in your opinion) you can post it there

Comment: @Andomar - why do you think the duplicate is inappropriate? All this code is doing is calculating the same as `FORMAT(Getdate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd H:00:00.00')` and the title indicates the use case is to group by hour

Comment: @Martin Smith SQL version 2019. The second one liner worked. Thank you. I did see other questions that grouped by the hour but but it would also remove the date it would just return the integer hour.

Comment: @MartinSmith What examples are there of a ten year old legacy question being updated by means of new answers and updated voting?

Comment: @Andomar - the duplicate is an example of that. The second answer on the page is referencing `DATETRUNC`

Comment: Curiously for all the discussion about whether or not the question has a duplicate, none of the commenters have actually added an answer?

Comment: @MartinSmith the top accepted answer is outdated and has 65 votes, the second answer has only 6 votes.  How well does that match today's software landscape?

Comment: There is no requirement that we aren't allowed to close questions as duplicate as we have to reserve top spot for some hypothetical better answer. If Jeff has an answer he wants to share he can post it on one of the many questions that already ask about this, same as every one else has to do. 65 votes is not an insurmountable obstacle for a better answer to overcome anyway

Comment: @MartinSmith - I do see your point and after thinking about the nature of this site, totally understand the reasoning. Shifting gears a bit... I don't know how to look at the "Closed History" to make sure, but I seem to recall that  the post that was cited for the "duplicate" asked for the hour to be "rounded to the nearest hour", which is different than truncating to the hour like the OP requested on this post. Also, the title of THIS post is terrible because the code example does not "GROUP BY Date and Hour".  It simply converts.

Comment: @JeffModen - Thanks! For reference you can click the icon (of a clock?!) underneath the voting arrows to see the history. The proposed dupe was a truncation based one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783745/truncate-date-to-only-hour-minute - and I agree this Q is not a poster boy that needs leaving open. If it was tagged with SQL Server 2022 (making `DATETRUNC` directly relevant) and had DDL and more details about proposed usage rather than just a mention of grouping in the title and a `SELECT` with no `FROM` or any other context then personally I'd be happy to have left it alone

Comment: @MartinSmith - Great tip on the history, Martin.  I didn't know that before.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original code from the OP **truncates** to the hour.  It does **NOT round** to the nearest hour.  It also does not "GROUP BY the Date and Hour", as the title suggests.  It only does the "truncation" to the hour.

With that in mind, here are some different solutions for SQL Server 2005 and up.

**Note1:** In the following, GETDATE() could be a column name from a table if the query reads from a table.

**Note2:** If the desired resolution is whole days, be cautious about just using CONVERT(DATE), which could cause a datatype mismatch.

**Note3:** Always watch your datatypes if such conversions are used for criteria.

```
--===== A solution for all versions of SQL Server for dates >= 1900-01-01.
     -- This will will work for minutes as well as hours provided that 
     -- you don't need a date result > 5983-01-24 02:07. Also, it should
     -- NOT be used for WEEK nor can it be used ISOWEEK.
 SELECT DATEADD(hh,DATEDIFF(hh,0,GETDATE()),0)
;
--===== Solution for all versions of SQL Server for dates >= 1753-01-01,
     -- which is the earliest date possible for the DATETIME datatype.
     -- This will will work for minutes as well as hours provided that 
     -- you don't need a date result > 5836-01-25 02:07. Also, it should
     -- NOT be used for WEEK nor can it be used ISOWEEK.
 SELECT DATEADD(hh,DATEDIFF(hh,'1753',GETDATE()),'1753')
;
--===== Slightly faster version of the solution immediately above but
     -- less obvious to newbies and neophytes.
 SELECT DATEADD(hh,DATEDIFF(hh,-53690,GETDATE()),-53690)
;
--===== The following solution works for all possible dates in SQL Server
     -- starting at 0001-01-01 (Inherently, SQL Server 2008 and up)
     -- This will will work for minutes as well as hours provided that 
     -- you don't need a date result > 4084-01-24 02:07. Also, it should
     -- NOT be used for WEEK nor can it be used ISOWEEK.
 SELECT DATEADD(hh,DATEDIFF(hh,'00010101',GETDATE()),CONVERT(DATETIME2,'00010101'))
;
--===== Solution for SQL Server 2022 and up
     -- This will work for any temporal resolution available for
     -- any date/time possible in SQL Server including WEEK and ISOWEEK.
     -- Unlike DATEDIFF, this also follows DATEFIRST for the WEEK datepart.
 SELECT DATETRUNC(hh,GETDATE())
;
```

Comment: Definitely the way to go. As I've remarked many times in the past, thanks to cultural/internationalization issues, solutions that rely on date strings are rarely the better option, and are almost always slower and more error-prone than we expect.