# Rounding milliseconds SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

In Microsoft SQL Server 2000, I have this data.

```
1900-01-01 00:10:10.830
1900-01-01 00:10:10.430
```

From the above column, I want to select the datetime and round off the milliseconds, in order to get the below output

```
1900-01-01 00:10:11
1900-01-01 00:10:10
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666866/t-sql-datetime-rounded-to-nearest-minute-and-nearest-hours-with-using-functions

Comment: Yes. I copied that question since it is not working on my sql version.

Comment: what version are you using, you don't say.

Comment: @Jodrell Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Comment: see the fiddle, it works, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/42581

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server 2008 and above, you can do use `DATETIME2`. `DATETIME2` is available in SQL Server 2008 and above - for more info see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/bb677335(v=sql.100).aspx):

```
SELECT CAST('1900-01-01 00:10:10.830' AS DATETIME2(0));
SELECT CAST('1900-01-01 00:10:10.430' AS DATETIME2(0));
```

[Confirmed Output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/42581)

For earlier version of SQL Sever, for example SQL Server 2000. You can do something like this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, DATEADD(ms, 500, CAST('1900-01-01 00:10:10.830' AS DATETIME))) , DATEADD(ms, 500, CAST('1900-01-01 00:10:10.830' AS DATETIME)));
SELECT DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, DATEADD(ms, 500, CAST('1900-01-01 00:10:10.430' AS DATETIME))) , DATEADD(ms, 500, CAST('1900-01-01 00:10:10.430' AS DATETIME)));
```

Comment: *`DATETIME2`: from SQL Server 2008 and up*

Comment: I'm getting this error. Line 1: Length or precision specification 0 is invalid.

Comment: @ElishTorres what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @ElishTorres, then you need to upgrade to a database from this decade or, add a tag to your question.

Comment: I copy pasted the code above on my sql and got that error.

Comment: @Donal oopps. It's not 2008. It's 2000. Sorry.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson It's 2000. I'm sorry.

Comment: @ElishTorres ok, I have added the SQL that should work with SQL Server 2000, I don't have SQL Server 2000 - so I could not test it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
     , DateAdd(ss, rounded_second, round_down_seconds) As result
FROM   (
        SELECT *
             , Round(nanoseconds / 1000.0, 0) As rounded_second
        FROM   (
                SELECT the_date
                     , DatePart(ms, the_date) As nanoseconds
                     , DateAdd(ss, DateDiff(ss, 0, the_date), 0) As round_down_seconds
                FROM   (
                        SELECT '1900-01-01 00:10:10.830' As the_date
                        UNION ALL 
                        SELECT '1900-01-01 00:10:10.430'
                       ) As x
               ) As y
       ) As z
```

I've split out each step to be as clear as possible.

If you want a single liner:

```
SELECT the_date
     , DateAdd(ss, Round(DatePart(ms, the_date) / 1000.0, 0), DateAdd(ss, DateDiff(ss, 0, the_date), 0)) As result
FROM   (
        SELECT '1900-01-01 00:10:10.830' As the_date
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT '1900-01-01 00:10:10.430'
       ) As x
```

Comment: This answer that will give overflow errors if you replace the value of the_date with getdate()

Comment: @t-clausen.dk correct. But that is not part of the original requirement by the OP. If this is an issue for you then you can tweak the value used in the DateDiff() comparison from 0 (=1900-01-01) to something more appropriate for your dataset e.g. 2000-01-01.