# T-SQL Azure Stream Analytics Rounding to Minute

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have the following SELECT clause in my Azure Stream Analytics Query:

`SELECT DateAdd(mi, DateDiff(mi, 0, DateAdd(s, 30, Max(timecreated))), 0) as 'timestamp'`

Which is giving the following error:

> Second parameter of 'DateDiff' in expression 'DateDiff ( mi , 0 , DateAdd(s, 30, Max ( timecreated ) ) )' has invalid type 'bigint'. 'datetime' is expected.

Admittedly, the code I'm using is copied from several similar threads on StackOverflow, such as [T-SQL datetime rounded to nearest minute and nearest hours with using functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666866/t-sql-datetime-rounded-to-nearest-minute-and-nearest-hours-with-using-functions), but I've no idea what to change the 0 to in my scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should have auto cast the 0 from bigint to datetime, but there may be some quirks with the Azure version of T-SQL.  Instead, use:

```
SELECT DATEADD(mi, 
  DATEDIFF(mi, CAST('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 
    DATEADD(s, 30, MAX(timecreated))),
  CAST('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime)) as 'timestamp'
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! My final code is: `DateAdd(mi, DateDiff(mi, CAST('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), DateAdd(s, 30, Max(timecreated))), CAST('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime)) as 'timestamp',` as `CAST(0 AS DateTime)` does not work on Azure T-SQL.

Comment: Updated answer with final solution.