# Modifying SQL table data in results - ie return as

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to edit the values of some rows in the results?

Specifically I want to be able to round off dates to the nearest hour inside the results themselves.

Comment: Usually any operations you can do within the database are available also when returning the data.

Comment: I'm on Microsoft SQL. 
How would I use round() on a time? All the info I can find uses numbers as a param.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL datetime rounded to nearest minute and nearest hours with using functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666866/t-sql-datetime-rounded-to-nearest-minute-and-nearest-hours-with-using-functions)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing:

```
SELECT DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute,0,DATETIME) / 30 * 30 ,0) AS "Rounded Time"
```