# How can get Time from the system? t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

From a stored procedure in T-SQL, I want to get the time from the system. So, if for example, the time from the system is 12:29, the function should to return 12:00, if the time of the system is 12:31 the function should to return 13:00.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL datetime rounded to nearest minute and nearest hours with using functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666866/t-sql-datetime-rounded-to-nearest-minute-and-nearest-hours-with-using-functions)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DATEADD` function:

```
DECLARE @time TIME = '12:31:00'

SELECT CAST(DATEADD(Hour,IIF(DATEPART(mi, @time)<=30,0,1),DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0, @time), 0)) AS TIME);
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/LYAT14695)**

How it works:

1. Truncate time to nearest hour
2. Add 1 hour if minutes > 30 (or change logic if you need to handle seconds as well)

**EDIT:**

Prior to SQL Server 2012 you could use `CASE` instead of `IIF`

```
DECLARE @time TIME = '12:31:00'

SELECT CAST(DATEADD(Hour,CASE WHEN DATEPART(mi, @time)<=30 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0, @time), 0)) AS TIME);
```

**[Rextester Demo 2](http://rextester.com/WID93006)**

Comment: Something to note is that `IIF()` is for 2012 +

Comment: Yes IIF is only for 2012+ i Have 2008

Comment: @bircastri It is not a problem. Just exchange IIF with CASE