# Round to nearest MINUTE or HOUR in Standard SQL BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

There are some easy short ways to round to nearest MINUTE for T-SQL as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666866/t-sql-datetime-rounded-to-nearest-minute-and-nearest-hours-with-using-functions).

I am looking to get the same short syntax for Standard SQL.

Comment: Which type are you working with? `DATETIME`? `TIMESTAMP`? `TIME`?

Comment: I had built an example for DateTime

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATETIME '2018-01-01 01:05:56' input_datetime 
)
SELECT input_datetime,
  DATETIME_TRUNC(input_datetime, MINUTE) rounded_to_minute,
  DATETIME_TRUNC(input_datetime, HOUR) rounded_to_hour
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result as

```sql
Row     input_datetime          rounded_to_minute       rounded_to_hour  
1       2018-01-01T01:05:56     2018-01-01T01:05:00     2018-01-01T01:00:00
```

For `TIMESTAMP` or `TIME` data types - you can use respectively -  `TIMESTAMP_TRUNC()` or `TIME_TRUNC()`

Answer (score 10):

There's some ambiguity in the question. The use of "round" in this context can be interpreted as "*truncate* to the nearest hour or minute," which the patterns so far demonstrate, and which probably has a closer analogy in `floor` than it does `round`. However, there are legitimate cases where one might want to truly "round" a timestamp to the nearest hour—that is, emulate a `round` operation. This is certainly doable:

```sql
with events as
(
  select timestamp('2020-04-21T18:21:55.967+00:00') as event_at
  union all
  select timestamp('2020-04-21T18:51:55.967+00:00') as event_at
)
select event_at
  , timestamp_trunc(event_at, hour) as event_truncated_hour
  , timestamp_trunc(timestamp_add(event_at, interval 30 minute), hour) as event_rounded_hour
from events
```

which yields

```
| event_at                         | event_truncated_hour           | event_rounded_hour            |
|----------------------------------|--------------------------------|-------------------------------|
| 2020-04-21T18:21:55.967+00:00    | 2020-04-21T18:00:00.000+00:00  | 2020-04-21T18:00:00.000+00:00 |
| 2020-04-21T18:51:55.967+00:00    | 2020-04-21T18:00:00.000+00:00  | 2020-04-21T19:00:00.000+00:00 |
```

Answer (score 1):

The same Standard SQL syntax is available in BQ as well

> Input as datetime **2018-01-01 01:05:56**

```
select 
    DATETIME_ADD(datetime '1800-01-01 00:00:00',
    INTERVAL DATETIME_DIFF(datetime '2018-01-01 01:05:56','1800-01-01 00:00:00',MINUTE) MINUTE) as rounded_to_minute,

    DATETIME_ADD(datetime '2010-01-01 00:00:00',
    INTERVAL DATETIME_DIFF(datetime '2018-01-01 01:05:56','2010-01-01 00:00:00',HOUR) HOUR) as rounded_to_hour
```

which produces:

```
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+--+
| Row |  rounded_to_minute  |   rounded_to_hour   |  |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+--+
|   1 | 2018-01-01T01:05:00 | 2018-01-01T01:00:00 |  |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+--+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `timestamp` then you can use `TIMESTAMP_TRUNC`:

[Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_trunc)

This also allow you to truncate by a specified timezone (so, for example you can specify the start of a day *for a specified timezone*. For example to truncate to the beginning of a day in Victoria, Australia:

`TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(sample_date_time, DAY, 'Australia/Victoria') as sample_date_time`

You can even use aggregates as the value to truncate e.g.

`TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(min(sample_date_time), DAY, 'Australia/Victoria') as sample_date_time,`