# Delete duplicated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I ve got duplicated rows in a temp table mainly because there are some date values which are seconds/miliseconds different to each other.

For example:

> 2018-08-30 12:30:19.000
>
> 2018-08-30 12:30:20.000

This is what causes the duplication.

How can I keep only one of those values? Let s say the higher one?

Thank you.

Comment: well, we need to see the rest of the data... and know your threshold for duplication? Would 2 seconds be a duplicate? 30 seconds?

Comment: it s roughly 6 mil rows. 60 seconds should be enough

Comment: The important part is the key of the table. "The rest of the data" here mostly means the other columns, what is the primary key, and maybe a few rows of sample data that would include one of these duplicates. We certainly do not need to see 6 million records to understand the problem fully, but not seeing any records is a bit of a hindrance.

Comment: what are the other columns... we need some sample data and expected results

Comment: `92860635 1.541666 27.4347685  2018-09-28 11:36:07.000 124 40 2018-09-01 01:10:03.000 2018-08-30 12:30:19.000 95 23` 
The only key is the first int value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, one method is to use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lead(ts) over (order by ts) as next_ts
      from t
     ) t
where next_ts is null or
      datediff(second, ts, next_ts) < 60;   -- or whatever threshold you want
```

Answer (score 1):

You could assign a `Row_Number` to each value, as follows:

```
Select *
, Row_Number() over 
              (partition by ObjectID, cast(date as date)... ---whichever criteria you want to consider duplicates
               order by date desc) --assign the latest date to row 1, may want other order criteria if you might have ties on this field
as RN
from MyTable
```

Then retain only the rows where `RN = 1` to remove duplicates.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666866/t-sql-datetime-rounded-to-nearest-minute-and-nearest-hours-with-using-functions) for examples of how to round your dates to the nearest hour, minute, etc. as needed; I used truncating to the day above as an example.